# why do I need parenthesis in this dictionary initializer, in F#

Tags: dictionary, f#, initialization

with these types:

```
type A =
    | AA
    | AB

type B =
    Dictionary<int, int>()
```

I initialize a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<A, B>(dict [ (A.AA, B()); (A.AB, B()) ])
```

but I do not understand why I need to put parenthesis after B, in the initialization code.

the following:

```
Dictionary<A, B>(dict [ (A.AA, B); (A.AB, B) ])
```

will not compile. I understand that 'B' may represent the type and 'B()' an instance of it, but I don't understand why the '()' would represent an instance?

As an additional question:

```
type B =
    Dictionary<int, int>()
```

and

```
type B =
    Dictionary<int, int>
```

both seem to work. Is any of the two preferred, and, if so, why?

Comment: You are confusing types with values. `B` is a type, `B()` is a value

Comment: I understand that it's what's happening in practice, but I don't really understand the syntax. In the second question for example, what difference do the () do? and in the first question, I get that B is the type and B() is an instance of that type, but I do not get the '()' syntax since I've been used to that () represents 'nothing' in F#

Comment: It's not "nothing", it's unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the declaration `type B = Dictionary<int, int>()` does not work for me. I get an error "*Unexpected symbol '(' in member definition*", exactly as I would expect. Are you sure it's working for you? Which version of F# are you using?

The type `Dictionary<_,_>` is a *class*. Classes are not the same as discriminated unions (which the type `A` is). They are a different sort of type.

In particular, to create a value of a class type, one needs to call a constructor and pass it some parameters. This is exactly what you're doing in your very own code:

```
Dictionary<A, B> (dict [ (A.AA, B()); (A.AB, B()) ])
^--------------^ ^---------------------------------^
    |                      |
 constructor               |
                           |
                        parameter passed to the constructor
```

Some classes have multiple constructors. `Dictionary` is one of such types.

Some constructors have no parameters, but you still have to call them. This is what you do with empty parens.

F# models parameterless .NET methods and constructors as functions that have a single parameter, and that parameter is of type unit. This is what you're doing when you say `B()`

```
B ()
^ ^^
|  |
|  single parameter of type unit
|
constructor
```

If you just say `B` without a parameter, then what you get is a function of type `unit -> B` - that is a function that expects a single parameter of type `unit` and when you pass it such parameter, it would return you a value of type `B`.

Comment: I think I understand where the confusion is: I should really look at type B as an equivalent of a macro where B gets substituted for its content (the dictionary class) that needs to get instantiated. I guess part of the confusion is that the keyword type is used in different scenarios and it creates different type of entities.
To answer your first question, I compiled the code on Jupyter Lab, macOS; it doesn't tell me if it's using .net core or mono, but I confirm (having just retested), it does compile with the parenthesis.